# Sorting array of records in ascending order

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects)

Given the array of record of students below - how would you sort them in ascending order using Javascript according to age?

```
students = [{
name: "timothy",
age: "9"},
{
name: "claire",
age: "12"},
{
name: "michael",
age: "20"}]
```

Comment: Ascending by what property? Why are the ages strings and not numbers?

Comment: Define the term of what you're sorting on first, because you can sort by age or name in your example. Age is easy by implementing a number of sort algorithms using integers. For name, you can convert to and ASCII representation and then again sort on the integer value. Check out quick sort on Wikipedia.

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759350/2247494)**

Answer (score 2):

To sort in ascending order by age, use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparator function:

```
students.sort(function (a, b)
{
    return a.age - b.age;
});

// students will be 
[{name: "timothy", age: "9"},
 {name: "claire", age: "12"},
 {name: "michael", age: "20"}]
```

Comment: Should the function perform a parseInt before performing the subtraction? I would imagine if it's done based on the string representation it might return goofy results.

Comment: @Joel `parseInt(age, 10)` would certainly work but is not strictly necessary. Subtraction coerces the operands to numbers.

Comment: That would return NaN if one of the values cant be transformed into number.

Comment: @Ivan true, but there was nothing in the question to suggest that the ages might be non-numeric strings.

Answer (score 0):

By age:

```
students = students.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.age) - parseFloat(b.age);
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `parseFloat` (subtraction will coerce to number) and you don't need the assignment (`Array.sort` is in-place).

Answer (score 0):

```
student.sort(function(a,b){

 if (a.name > b.name)
     return -1;
 return 1;

});
```

Comment: Cannot use `>` on `Object`. And what about when `a === b`?

Answer (score 0):

Read over this example:

```
var marks = new Array(10,12,11,20,2);
        for(var i=0;i<marks .length;i++) //Hold the first element
    {
        for(var j=i+1;j<marks.length;j++) //Hold the next element from the first element
        {
            if(Number(marks[i]) > Number(marks[j])) //comparing first and next element
            {
                tempValue = marks[j];   
                marks[j] = marks[i];
                marks[i] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }
        document.write(marks);
```

Comment: That is a **terrible** sort implementation.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work? jsfiddle.net/EH8Pm/2/

Comment: @jason: In your jfiddle example you only swap the ages, instead of the whole array elements. Also, you output `marks` and not `students`.

Comment: @jason: actually, not even that: you are accessing `students.age[i]` instead of `students[i].age`. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/EH8Pm/3/ for a working version (though as Matt says, it is not a good algorithm).

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759350/2247494)**

Answer (score 0):

```
students.sort(function(a,b){
      if (+a.age > +b.age) return 1;
      return -1;
});
// Now the object is ordered by age (min to max)
```

In case you are wondering, **+a.age** is the same as **Number(a.age)**

Comment: What happens if two people have the same age?

Comment: They get together in an position based on their previous position in the array (kind of random). If you want to order them alphabetically when ages are equal you can write this at the beggining `if (+a.age == +b.age) return [a.name,b.name].sort()[0] == a.name ? -1 : 1;`